# what is service mesh in container Load Balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

When i read about Load Balancers & containers.Looking for clear understanding of service mesh in Load balancer and how it is useful in containers.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of service meshes, there is istio coming onto my mind, as well as envoy proxy.

https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/
https://www.envoyproxy.io/

What is that all about? To many things to squeeze into an answer over here, but this is a good article with several practical examples what features istio can provide:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/06/introduction-istio-makes-mesh-things/

Answer (score 1):

Istio is coming to be well known for this. It operates as a ‘sidecar’ container, which just means it is another container in the same pod, so will co-locate with another container and can influence network traffic for that container.

Put simply, a service mesh is effectively a collection of agents (typically for a micro-service architecture), but somewhat inverted to traditional HA approaches with load-balancing virtual servers.

So for example: say an container app A wants to talk to service S; instead of S being an load-balancer (eg haproxy), you might have multiple instances of Ss. A will have a sidecar that has the property of when A wants to connect to S, the sidecar will route traffic to one of the Ss.

Imagine the difference in traffic throughout a microservice architecture; you’ve reduced the number of choke points because you’ve effectively got a load balancer for every client.

Now consider what else you could do with this sort of thing; want to authenticate services in a standard way without having to implement that in your container app? Perhaps a sidecar container could do that for you.

Want to have some nice circuit-breaker logic to help prevent timeouts and provide for graceful failure? Sidecar!

What about feature-flag support, so you can do things like dark-launch or fail-out features gracefully to cope with load. Sidecar!

How about helping to monitor, visualise and analyse traffic within your architecture? Monorail! Monorail! .... Sidecar!

What I’m trying to say is that you can make your application as simple as a green unicorn speaking http, and have something else care about the infrastructure and things that Developers typically hate thinking about (ssl, load-balancing, etc)

Or at least I hope that’s what the service mesh promise is about.